# MLE of a Laplace density

Tags: maximum-likelihood, laplace-distribution

How do you evaluate MLE of  theta, considering a simple random sample of size n from a Laplace density?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sample $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ from the Laplace distribution with parameter $\theta$, the log-likelihood is given by

$$l(\theta) = \ln (\frac{1}{2}) - \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - \theta|$$

which is proportional to

$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - \theta|$$

This is known as the [mean absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) and the estimator that minimizes this function is the median, $\hat{\theta} = \text{median}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$